# turn two sql queries into one with a subquery: top 1 row of query from subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table structure:

```
wwwID   eeeID   www1    eee1    property1   property2
1       1       aa2     ddd1    bbb1        adfsdfs
2       1       aa1     ddd1    bbb2        lasdkjfs
3       1       aa3     ddd1    bbb3        doafijsd
4       1       aa1     ddd1    bbb4        doifjdoifs
5       2       bb2     ddd2    ccc1        dofidsjfois
6       2       bb3     ddd2    ccc2        peowrpoerwe
7       2       aa1     ddd2    ccc3        dpofsdopfsd
```

my first query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT eeeID FROM tInf WHERE www1='aa1'
```

this query returns:

```
eeeID
1
2
```

then I pass the results to a second query:

```
SELECT * FROM tInf WHERE eeeID='" & eeeID & "' LIMIT 1
```

(TOP 1 in mysql syntax)

final result:

```
eeeID, eee1, property1, property2:
1, ddd1, bbb1, adfsdfs
2, ddd2, ccc1, dofidsjfois
```

I tried combining this into one query

```
SELECT * FROM tInf WHERE eeeID IN (
       SELECT DISTINCT eeeID FROM tInf WHERE www='aa1'
) LIMIT 1
```

but this apparently only brings one total result, not one result per subquery result. Is there any way of doing this in a single query ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one output row for each `eeeID` group; this is done with GROUP BY.

SQLite allows [bare columns in aggregate queries](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg); you can use MIN() to get the row with the smallest value in the group, or just do not use MIN() to get some random row from the group:

```
SELECT *,
       MIN(wwwID)  -- optional
FROM tInf
WHERE eeeID IN (SELECT eeeID
                FROM tInf
                WHERE www1 = 'aa1')
GROUP BY eeeID;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is correct. Maybe one minor improvement: SELECT DISTINCT eeID in the subquery

Comment: That would not improve anything; SQLite does this automatically for IN.

Answer (score 1):

why not just select the distinct fields

```
select distinct eeeID, eee1, property from tInf;
```

Comment: I updated my table structure. Because each eeeID may have more than one rows with www1="aa1" and that query would return three rows as result

Comment: if you don't select `www1`, the above query will return two rows only. Do you want only the first property ?

Comment: Can you post your exact expected output :)